# HJB with discontinuity at boundary

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, optimization, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I have an optimization problem whose value function I denote by $U(x,t)$ where $x\in [0,1]$ is a state variable and $t\in [0,1]$ is time. The HJB equation for my optimization problem when $x<1$ is given by

$$
U(x,t)=\frac{\partial U(x,t)}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial^2 U(x,t)}{\partial x^2}(1-x)
$$
with boundary condition $U(x,1)=Y(x)$, where $Y(x)$ is a continuous function with $\lim_{x\to 1} Y(x)=y$.

The HJB equation for $x=1$ is instead given by 
$$
U(1,t)=\frac{\partial U(1,t)}{\partial t}-C
$$
where $C>0$ is a constant, with boundary conditions $U(1,1)=y$.

Does this suggest that $U(x,t)$ is not continuous at $x=1$ when $t<1$. If so, does that mean the solution I derive from the HJB equation is not (necessarily) the solution to the optimization problem?

Comment: Let me ask some questions. First, what is big $T$. Shouldn't it be 1? Does $C=0$, or no? (It seem to me it should be, just putting $x=1$ in the first equation).  What implies discontinuity for you? I didn't see anything which implies discontinuity. (Sorry if I misunderstood something).

Comment: Yes, $T=1$. My bad!. What seems like a discontinuity to me is that for $\frac{\partial U(x,t)}{\partial x}(1-x)$ to be a constant $C$ at $x=1$, we would need $\frac{\partial U(x,t)}{\partial x}$ to go to infinity.

Comment: Why it should be $\infty$? Without exact form of $\frac{\partial^{2} U(x,t)}{\partial {x}^{2}}$ you can't say where it go to infinity or 0. So it can be just any constant. However if the derivative is bounded, (which is most often the case) it exactly goes to 0.

Comment: What I mean is that $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\partial U(x,t)}{\partial x}(1-x)=C\neq 0$ only if $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\partial U(x,t)}{\partial x}=\infty$. If the second derivative is bounded, then $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\partial U(x,t)}{\partial x}(1-x)=0$ which then would also imply a discontinuity.